# PhpStorm isn't doing code completion with large file

Tags: phpstorm, filesize, code-completion, xero-api, vendor

I've just installed [this library](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2). PhpStorm does its usual code completion, except for the `\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi` class. The `\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\IdentityApi` class in the same folder works just fine.

The file is quite big - 2,560KB. If I delete roughly half of the 65,000 lines from the class (and it works whether it's the first half or the second half) then I get my code completion back. In fact, I can delete just the last 3,000 or so lines (getting the file down to 2,499KB) and it works.

I've also tried a quick regex find/replace to remove all the `@throws` PHPDoc comments. This got the file down to 2,491KB and hey presto, code completion works fine.

If I had to make a guess I'd say it's not doing code completion with source files over 2.5MB or something, but I can't find any setting for this.

Any way to get code completion going with this file short of deleting stuff from it (which will be restored next time I do a Composer update anyway)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your info (especially the mentioned file size and the fact that it starts to work after reducing it) you have hit a limit of max file size that IDE is willing to parse and index.

Solution: configure `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` option using `Help | Edit Custom Properties` command. By default it has a value of `2500` (size in KB). Set it to `3000` or so (to cover your file size) *and restart IDE* (it reads and applies settings from `idea.properties` file on start only).

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=3000
```

P.S. Do not put that value too big as it may cause other performance issues.